# Find context free grammar for $u v w v^R$

Tags: context-free-grammar

The question is to find a CFG for this language:

$$\{ u v w v^R\ |\ u, v, w \in \{a,b\}^+,\ |u| = |w| = 2\},$$

where $v^R$ denotes the reverse of $v$.

I've been trying, but I'm not sure how to have $w$ in between $v$ and $v^R$.

Just for the v and v^R, I can do S -> aSa | bSb | epsilon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a non-terminal symbol $A$ that generates any string of two terminal symbols and disappears. If $S$ is the initial symbol, have a production $S\to AB$, where $B\to aBa\mid bBb\mid aAa\mid bAb$.

Comment: you mean like A -> aa|ab|ba|bb|epsilon ?

Comment: @Herious  You don't want the epsilon, as you don't want $A$ to be empty.

Comment: oh I see, thanks so much, may I ask how did you come up with the solution? These problems seem to not have any rule to solve...

Comment: @Herious: The idea of a non-terminal that spits out matched pairs on opposite sides is pretty standard. Once you have that, it's not hard to see that you can build anything between the resulting strings $v$ and $v^R$ that doesn't depend on whatever is outside them. Similarly,it's not hard to see that you can also build anything before or after them that can be generated by a non-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

A simple application of the pumping lemma shows that this is $\mathbb{NOT \space A \space REGULAR \space LANGUAGE}$ and so you $\mathbb{CANOT}$ use a regular expression. You need to define a CFG.